# Checking from Python which easy_install version is available?

Tags: python, setuptools, package-managers, distribute

Is there a way to check programmatically, from Python, if the user has setuptools's "easy_install" available or the distribute version of "easy_install"?

I'd like to know which of those is available (and ideally which is "in-use" by the system.)

How can this be done? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For easy-install based

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('setuptools')
setuptools 0.6c11 (t:\tmp\easyinstall\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg)
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('setuptools').project_name
'setuptools'
```

For distribute based

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('setuptools')
distribute 0.6.31 (t:\tmp\distribute\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.31-py2.7.egg)
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('setuptools').project_name
'distribute'
```

Comment: How do I parse this? Can just look for "setuptools" versus "distribute" as first word of output?

Comment: @user248237 Use the project_name property. I have updated my example

Answer (score 1):

Use the included [`pkg_resources` library](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html) to detect if `setuptools` is available and if so, what version it is. If you cannot import `pkg_resources`, there is no `setuptools` library installed, full stop:

```
try:
    import pkg_resources
except ImportError:
    print "No setuptools installed for this Python version"
else:
    dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution('setuptools')
    print dist.project_name, dist.version
```

The project name is either `distribute` or `setuptools`; for me this prints:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution('setuptools')
>>> print dist.project_name, dist.version
distribute 0.6.32
```

See the [`Distribution` attributes documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#distribution-attributes) for further details on what information is available.